# Lost my phone. Can I still locate it?

Tags: cyanogenmod, nexus-4, 5.0-lollipop, lost-phone, location-services

So I lost my phone a few days ago. Either somebody found it, or it is somewhere in the snow, soaked with water.

It's a Nexus 4 running CM12 nightly with GPS **completely** turned off. Google's Android Device Manager shows last online time to be January 10th, which is the day I lost the phone.
It says "Location unavailable" and nothing more. AFAIK, it should show that my GPS is turned off, or that I disabled google location reporting, but it shows none of it. Does this mean my device is turned off -or- wiped?
Can I somehow check the exact last online time (hh:mm) ?

I don't have any tracking apps installed.
Is it possible to locate it by using the IMEI?

Comment: How would a disconnected service know that lack of locatability is due to GPS off, or the device has GPS on but it sits in an inaccessible place? There is no distinction. Just like the analogy: I can't see. Is it because I'm blind or just eyes closed?

Comment: What do you mean by completely turned off? Remember that without gps any app will only get a radius around your phone but less than 40 meters is very unlikely